# How to SUM a column based on range and another column being distinct?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have column 1 and it has dates.

I have column 2 and it has inventory sold.

The dates are duplicated from several systems - which means for a given date there are at least 7-10 numbers for inventory sold.

We simply want to take the highest amount for a specific date and show the SUM of that column for inventory.  Mean we are only adding 1 inventory amount per date.

Comment: Have you tried pivot table?

Comment: Have you tried sumif or sumifs?